# how to compare total file

Tags: scripting, diff

Suppose i have 2 config files such as:
file 1:

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
```

File 2:

```
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
```

if you see carefully, you'll see together have a line begin with `virtua_gid_*` but file 1 have it in end of file but file 2 have it head of file.

Suppose i have 2 files with same lines with difference positions , but positions not important for me, to be or not to be is important.

HOW CAN I COMPARE MY FILES?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the positions are not important, you can sort the files and then, perform a diff.  You will have to save the sorted files in temporary area.

```
sort file1 > /tmp/file1
sort file2 > /tmp/file2
diff /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2
```

You may also want to try `vimdiff` instead of `diff`.

Answer (score 3):

If the files have only simple `<name> = <value>` lines into (like your example) you can do something like this:

```
$ cat file1 | sort > /tmp/sortedfile1
$ cat file2 | sort > /tmp/sortedfile2
$ diff /tmp/sortedfile1 /sortedfile2
```

This will work as long there is the same number of spaces around `=`

Comment: There's no need to pipe `cat` into `sort` since `sort` accepts a filename as an argument.

Comment: How is this different to the answer already posted by @unxnut? Apart from the [useless use of cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat) of course.

Comment: @terdon It's possible that it was being written while unxnut's was posted.

Comment: @j883376 ah, yes indeed, fair enough.

Comment: @ terdon : I'm a slow writer: @unxnut beat me for 2 minutes - yes I know it's a better form avoid using cat, but its't wrong. Have I to cancell my answer ?

Comment: @DavAlPi you don't have to do anything. _I_ have to learn to be more patient with people.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid using temp files if you use sub shells:

```
diff <(sort fileA) <(sort fileB)
```

Another useful program is [`meld`](http://meldmerge.org/) which is a very nice GUI for `diff`.